# change quantity in shopping cart

Tags: php, magento

I have a weird problem nobody seems to get. exept me offcourse :)
I have added an new/custom promotion rule (app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Validator.php)
Everything works fine but i want to update the shopping cart quantity. So if i add 10 products to my cart I want to add one product for free. so, buy 10 get 11 products.

```
case 'buy_x_get_y_free':
$x = $rule->getDiscountStep(); // 10
$y = $rule->getDiscountAmount(); // 1

$free = 0;

for( $i=$x; $i<=$qty; $i+=$x ){
   $free+=$y;
}

$discountAmount    = $free*$itemPrice;
$baseDiscountAmount= $free*$baseItemPrice;

$newQty = $qty + $free; // Should be 11 right?
$item->setQty($newQty);

break;
```

Well the script works. nut the 'new' quantity is 12 instead of 11. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

after discussing this with the original poster here is a new idea

when the validation script is called it is running the whole script again apparently and using the `$qty` from the `$item` object set by `$item->setQty($newQty);` so the second time the script runs `$qty=11` and then 1 gets added again to bring it to 12 instead store the quantities in 2 separate variables like `$qty` and `$free`

```
case 'buy_x_get_y_free':    
$x = $rule->getDiscountStep(); // 10    
$y = $rule->getDiscountAmount(); // 1    

$free = 0;    

for( $i=$x; $i<=$qty; $i+=$x ){    
   $free+=$y;    
}    

$discountAmount    = $free*$itemPrice;    
$baseDiscountAmount= $free*$baseItemPrice;    


$item->setQty($qty);
$item->setFree($free);

break;
```

you will need to add `$free` into the `$item` object code

try that

Comment: so what does your setQty() function look like? maybe set the Qty inside the function to 0 first then add newQty to it?

Comment: the problem is (i think) is that the validator.php is called 2 times while updating the shopping cart. 

checkout/cart/updatePost/ and here checkout/cart/

Everything works fine (prices, tax, etc) exept the quantity. Am i the only one with this problem? its driving me nuts. working 2 day on this 'little' issue. :(

Comment: we can't know if you are the only one with the issue because we can't see any of the stuff outside of the code you posted, maybe the problem is with the validator.php but we don't have that file to look at, if you could post it in your main question then we can make a better judgment of that, if your code is all hand written then you are probably the only one with this problem, if on the other hand you downloaded this code somewhere and others are using it, then maybe they are having the same issue

Comment: well its just in the magento core (1.4.1.1)
app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Validator.php

Ive just modify it to change the quantity.

Comment: cool hope it works, if so vote me up or give me the big green check mark :) good luck

Comment: well thats the problem. it doesn't work correct. 

The script get executed. the quantity is 11. after that the script get executed again. now the quantity is 12. And that there, is my problem :)

Comment: I think then you need two separate variables the original Quantity and the Quantity after bonus maybe `qty` and `bonusQty` so that each time the script is run it uses `qty` , it sounds like what is happening is that you run it with the orignal `qty=10` it is calculated and changed to 11 and run again and the user has at least 10 products so they are given a bonus again of 1 bringing the total to 12 so if you keep separate varibles `qty` would be 10 and `bonusQty` would be 1 and each time the script is run they should be the same ebause `qty` isn't changing

Comment: Yep I thinks thats right. But how should I do this? Any sample code?